# How do I pass shared preferences from a service to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, sharedpreferences

I am trying to pass data through shared preferences from a Service class to a Fragment class.

I have encountered no syntax error, but there is a logic error as I do not get the text view updated with the updated step counter I want in StepsFragment.

I am running a step counter in `StepsService.java` and I'm trying to pass the information to `StepsFragment.java`.

I have tried these following solutions:

[Access shared preference from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423553/access-shared-preference-from-a-service)

[Can I get data from shared preferences inside a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558550/can-i-get-data-from-shared-preferences-inside-a-service)

This is my code in `StepsService.java`

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final long timeInterval = 1000;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    // ------- code for task to run
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("DeviceToken",String.valueOf(stepsCounter));
                    editor.apply();
                    addNotification(String.valueOf(stepsCounter));
                    // ------- ends here
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

This is my code in `StepsFragment.java`

```
    public void startService(View view) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),StepsService.class);
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String deviceToken = prefs.getString("DeviceToken", null);
        tv_steps.setText(deviceToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fragment` you call `startService()` and immediate after that you read the `SharedPreferences`. This won't work. The call to `startService()` is asynchronous. It basically just requests that Android start the `Service`. This will happen at some time in the future, but definitely NOT immediately.

It will take some time for the `Service` to be started and for the `SharedPreferences` to be updated.

You could have your `Service` send a broadcast `Intent` when it updates the `SharedPreferences` and your `Fragment` or `Activity` could register to be notified of this broadcast `Intent` and use that as a trigger to update the `View`.

Or you could simply wait some time before checking the `SharedPreferences`.